# Using SQL join to retrieve set of data for each different value in a column

Tags: sql-server, join

I am working on retrieving data from two SQL tables on SQL Server in which I am trying to get all rows from right table for each distinct value in a column in left table no matter if there is a match or not

For example I have two tables named products and Deals with following data

Products table

```
Id Product
1  ABC
2  XYZ
3  PQR
```

Deals Table

```
Id  TradeDate  Product Volume   Price    Delivery
56  2014-12-08  ABC     2500    -3.25   2015-01-01 
57  2014-12-08  ABC     2500    -3.4    2015-02-01 
63  2014-12-08  PQR     2500    -7      2015-01-01 
64  2014-12-08  PQR     2500    -7      2015-01-01
```

I applied following query to the above tables

```
SELECT
         FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy') AS Delivery,

         b.Product,COUNT(a.Id) AS Trades, 
         ROUND(((6.2898*SUM(a.Volume ))/DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery), 0))))*0.001,4) AS BBLperDay,
         SUM(a.Volume) AS M3,       
         ROUND(SUM(a.Volume*a.Price)/Sum(a.Volume),4) AS WeightedAverage
FROM     Deals AS a right outer join Products AS b 
         ON a.Product=b.Product 
         AND CAST(a.TradeDate as date)='2014-12-08' 
GROUP BY b.Product,CAST(a.TradeDate as date), 
         DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery),0),  FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy')
```

And I got following results

```
 Delivery     Product    Trades  BBLperDay   M3  WeightedAverage
 January 2015   ABC         1   0.5072      2500      -3.25
 February 2015  ABC         1   0.5616      2500      -3.4
 January 2015   PQR         2   1.0145      5000        -7
 (null)         XYZ         0   (null)      (null)      (null)
```

The above results are expected for the query but I am trying a way to get the results such that from the above results I want all rows in `Products table` for each distinct `Delivery` value by making `Delivery value` as default for every equivalent result and other fields be `NULL` as follows

```
 Delivery     Product    Trades  BBLperDay   M3  WeightedAverage
  January 2015   ABC        1   0.5072      2500      -3.25
  January 2015   PQR        2   1.0145      5000        -7
  January 2015   XYZ        0   (null)      (null)      (null)
  February 2015  ABC        1   0.5616      2500      -3.4
  February 2015  XYZ        0   (null)      (null)      (null)
  February 2015  PQR        0   (null)      (null)      (null)
```

The above results can be explained as from actual results I have January 2015 Delivery for products ABC and PQR but the Products table as one more product XYZ which is missing for January 2015, so I added XYZ for January 2015 with Delivery as January 2015 and remaining NULL.
Same is the case with February 2015 Delivery it has only ABC so I added products XYZ and PQR to the results.

Please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db1508/3

```
May I know a good way to get this data?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just build out that 'backbone' of delivery products first and put your original query against it with a left join.  Shown here with CTEs.

```
WITH deliveryProducts AS
(
     SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy') AS Delivery, b.Product 
     FROM DEALS as a, PRODUCTS as b Where CAST(a.TradeDate as date)='2014-12-08'
)
, deliveryActuals AS
(
     SELECT
           FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy') AS Delivery,

           b.Product,ISNULL(COUNT(a.Id),0) AS Trades, 
           ROUND(((6.2898*SUM(a.Volume ))/DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery), 0))))*0.001,4) AS BBLperDay,
           SUM(a.Volume) AS M3,       
           ROUND(SUM(a.Volume*a.Price)/Sum(a.Volume),4) AS WeightedAverage

     FROM
           Deals AS a right outer join Products AS b 
           ON a.Product=b.Product 
           AND CAST(a.TradeDate as date)='2014-12-08'

     GROUP BY
           b.Product,CAST(a.TradeDate as date), 
           DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery),0),  FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy')
)

SELECT
     dp.Delivery, dp.Product, trades, BBLperDay, M3, WeightedAverage
FROM
     deliveryProducts dp

LEFT JOIN deliveryActuals da
     on dp.Delivery = da.Delivery
     and dp.product = da.Product

ORDER BY dp.Delivery
```

Here it is in your [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db1508/6)

Comment: This works almost fine except that it returns all the rows for each distinct value in Delivery. I want them only when there is at least one row which satisfies TradeDate='---' condition. For example see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db1508/7 where I changed trade date in where condition. In that the number of rows should be zero.

Comment: I was able to figure it by adding where statement in deliveryProducts. here it is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db1508/9

Comment: whoops, sorry for the missing filter.  I've added it as you did in your sqlfiddle.